# Using TIGER/Line shape files, how do I get address coordinates?

Tags: ogr2ogr, linestring, united-states

I've downloaded addressfeature shapefiles from TIGER/Line on the Census Bureau website. I converted one file to CSV using ogr2ogr. I get the following sample output:

```
WKT,TLID,TFIDL,TFIDR,ARIDL,ARIDR,LINEARID,FULLNAME,LFROMHN,LTOHN,RFROMHN,RTOHN,ZIPL,ZIPR,EDGE_MTFCC,ROAD_MTFCC,PARITYL,PARITYR,PLUS4L,PLUS4R,LFROMTYP,LTOTYP,RFROMTYP,RTOTYP,OFFSETL,OFFSETR
"LINESTRING (-98.730002999999982 37.659596999999991,-98.730001 37.659660999999986,-98.729996999999983 37.659855999999991,-98.729995999999986 37.65992099999999)",161042451,202265803,202266201,400110711124,,110200839772,Stout St,1409,1499,,,67124,,S1400,S1400,O,,,,I,,,,N,N
```

I understand the LINESTRING (etc etc etc) portion are the coordinates for the address range (in this case, 1409-1499 Stout St).

How can I get the exact coordinates for an address, such as 1431 Stout St?

Comment: I'm stuck at the same place. Did you find any solution to this question. Please let me know. Thanks -Mohammed